# Python numpy: see if an array is symmetric within a tolerance

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm looking to come up with a function that takes a 2-dimensional square array and returns a boolean value that reflects whether `a` is symmetric, within tolerance tolerance, to `a`.

my code looks like this:

```
for i in range(len(a)):
    for j in range(len(a[0])):
        if abs(a[i][j] - a.transpose()[j][i]) <= tol:
            a == a.transpose().all
```

and its come to my attention that when i return(a) im not actually returning what I want and im not sure how to fix this.

Comment: You can use `np.allclose(a, a.T, reltol, abstol)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can vectorize the calculation:

```
def is_symmetric(a):
    return (np.abs(a - a.T) <= tol).all()
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Im still a little confused though on if i add a return(a) at the end of this line or if I need to add more code. Im new at this so your help is greatly appreciated

Comment: If you want to return True or False, i.e. the condition, you could just return this line. `return (np.abs(a - a.T) <= tol).all()`.

Comment: Why didn't you use `np.allclose(a, a.T, atol=tol)`?

Comment: @NilsWerner I think the credit belongs to the comment :), and besides a direct answer here is about the same concise as `np.allclose`.