# Python mean shift clustering of complex-number numpy array

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, scikit-learn, linear-discriminant, mean-shift

I’ve inherited some code that was written about a year ago, so I guess back then it was using [numpy 1.13](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/releases/tag/v1.13.3) (now v1.15.2), [scipy 1.00rc](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/releases/tag/v1.0.0rc1) (now v1.1.0), and [sklearn 0.19](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/releases/tag/0.19.1) (now v.0.20.0).

It implements [Fisher’s LDA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_discriminant_analysis) to reduce an *n*-dimensional space to an 1…*n*-1 dimensional space which produces a numpy array of complex numbers as its result (due to floating-point imprecision). That array is then cheery-picked and fed into [`sklearn.cluster.MeanShift`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.MeanShift.html) which immediately throws an exception:

```
  File "/…/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/cluster/mean_shift_.py", line 416, in fit
    X = check_array(X)
  File "/…/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py", line 531, in check_array
    _ensure_no_complex_data(array)
  File "/…/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py", line 354, in _ensure_no_complex_data
    "{}\n".format(array))
ValueError: Complex data not supported
```

I am still learning the mathematical details of what’s going on here, but it strikes me as odd that this code was declared “runnable”.

Am I missing something here? Have version changes brought about this regression, or is there a more fundamental code flaw? How would I go about fixing this issue?

Comment: @PaulPanzer, many values in `X` are `1.70078660e+00+0.j`, and a fairly small number of values is e.g. `3.10415554e+00-0.31921105j`. I could just call [`X.real`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.real.html) and proceed with that result, and see what happens… ?

Comment: The complex arrays are the Eigenvalues and Eigenvectors of the covariance matrix in LDA. In fact, there is a `warnings.simplefilter('ignore', np.ComplexWarning)` right after, which indicates some intent to deal with complex results. However, a few lines down the code then raises the assertion, rendering it IMO not “runnable”. (PS: `np.iscomplex(X)` returns an array of rather sparse `True` values.)

Comment: Well… `eigvals, eigvecs = np.linalg.eig(Y)` where `Y` here is real (`np.iscomplexobj(Y) → False`), and the results are then complex.

Comment: Hmm It seems that `np.allclose(Y, Y.T)` gives me `False` (according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42908334/checking-if-a-matrix-is-symmetric-in-numpy#42913743)), i.e. `Y` isn’t symmetric. However, `eigh(Y)` does return a real matrix.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181190/discussion-between-jens-and-paul-panzer).

Comment: I've made an answer, since one doesn't get notified of new chat entries.

Answer (score 0):

In comments/chat we have identified at least one problem which is that the numerical eigen decomposition of

```
(cov_w + I)^-1 @ cov_b                       (1)
```

is not real as it should but returns significant imaginary components. Here @ is matrix multiplication, cov_w and cov_b are covariance matrices and I is the identity matrix. This can be fixed by computing the matrix square root of (cov_w + I)^-1 lets call it SQ and then using the fact that (1) is similar to

```
SQ @ cov_b @ SQ                              (2)
```

hence has the same eigenvalues and if V are the eigenvectors of (2) then the (right) eigenvectors of (1) are SQ @ V.

What we have gained is that because (2) is a symmetric matrix its eigen decomposition can be computed using `numpy.linalg.eigh` which guarantees purely real results. `eigh` can also be used to compute SQ, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_root_of_a_matrix). Be sure to bypass the inverse and apply `eigh` directly on `cov_w + I` or even `cov_w`.