# How would I go about fixing 'list index out of range' error in this Python code?

Tags: python, matrix, symmetry

I am trying to write a function that would be able to check the symmetry of a matrix that the user inputs. If the matrix is symmetrical, true is printed. If not, false is printed.

```
def symmetric(mat, N): 
    for i in range(N): 
        for j in range(N): 
            if (mat[i][j] != mat[j][i]): 
                return False
    return True

mat = []
if (symmetric(mat, 3)): 
    print ('true')
else: 
    print ('false')
```

The problem started once I added `mat = []`. `IndexError: list index out of range` is shown once I run the function.

I added a predefined matrix `mat = [[1, 2, 3], [2, 5, 4], [3, 4, 7]]` and it works perfectly but I need the user to input the matrix

The end result should look similar to this

```
>>> m1 = [[1, 2, 3], [2, 5, 4], [3, 4, 7]]
>>> symmetric(m1)
True
```

Answer (score 1):

What might be a bit more helpful is to use a [numpy array](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.array.html). It allows you to leverage the `shape` attribute to check if the matrix is square, and then you don't need to input a dimension size

```py
import numpy as np 

mat = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [2, 5, 4], [3, 4, 7]])

def symmetric(mat):
    rows, cols = mat.shape
    if rows != cols:
         raise ValueError("Invalid matrix isn't square")

    for i in range(rows):
        for j in range(cols):
            if (mat[i][j] != mat[j][i]): 
                    return False
    return True

try:
    is_symmetric = symmetric(mat)
except ValueError as e:
    print(e)
```

Numpy is a package you'll need to `pip install`, but this allows you to pre-emptively handle the non-square case pretty easily. Furthermore, the `allclose` function can allow you to quickly check the symmetric nature of an array as mentioned in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42908334/checking-if-a-matrix-is-symmetric-in-numpy), or as @Sheldore suggested:

```py
def symmetric(mat):
    if (mat.T == mat).all():
        return True
    return False

mat = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [2, 5, 4], [3, 4, 7]])
```

### Native List Approach

You could use a list comprehension approach in combination with the `all` operation:

```py
def symmetric(mat, N):
    # This is a pretty naive way to check the dimensions in a similar fashion
    # as np.shape, but this gets the thought process across
    row, col = len(mat[0][:]), len(mat[:][0])

    if row != col:
        raise ValueError("Non-square matrix is invalid")

    if all([mat[i][j] == mat[j][i] for i, j in zip(range(row), range(col))]:
        return True
    return False
```

Comment: Unfortunately for this assignment, Numpy isn't allowed. My professor wants us to experience the entire process of not using imports... I know, it sucks. But thank you!

Comment: That makes it a good exercise, I'll leave this answer here for others just in case

Comment: If you are already importing numpy, then why to mix things and use a loop. Simply do `if (mat==mat.T).all():    print (True)`

Comment: @Sheldore which is why I linked that other question

Comment: @C.Nivs: My bad. Missed it. Anyway, my answer is something different from the linked one so I will leave it as a comment

Comment: @Sheldore good to note either way, I've added your suggestion into my answer

Answer (score 0):

```
mat = []
try:
    if (symmetric(mat, 3)): 
        print ('true')
    else: 
        print ('false')
except IndexError:
    print('Invalid matrix, try again')
```

Comment: This works, except for it doesn't allow user input. It automatically prints ```Invalid input. false```